# Python selenium chrome still showing up even though I passed headless

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to run the chrome driver headless. So to do that I passed in the --headless argument when I created an instance of my driver, yet it is still showing a browser.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from fake_useragent import UserAgent

ua = UserAgent()
user_agent = ua.random

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
#chrome_options.add_argument("--window-size=1920x1080")
#chrome_options.add_argument(f'user-agent={user_agent}')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
```

Can someone help me figure out why chrome is spawing a web browser that is visible when I had thought that the --headless argument would hide it?

Comment: What version of chrome do you have? I think chrome headless requires min 59 on Lin/Mac and 60 on Windows, If you have anything lower than that

Comment: I have no idea to be honest, I will download the latest there is but I downloaded this driver in the last 2 months so I expected it would support it.

Comment: Driver can only support what the browser actually support, it is a communicator between selenium and chrome

Comment: Ah that looks like it fixed the problem! Thanks a ton man! I just needed to update my driver!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few things you should make sure

- If using Mac/Linux then chrome version should be minimum 59
- If using Windows then chrome version should be minimum 60
- Use the latest chromedriver as well to make sure you don't have compatibility issue